# CLLocation: Longitude and Latitude registering as 0.000

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

There is an issue with my iOS application in finding the location in longitude and latitude where it is registering as longitude 0.000 and latitude 0.000 when trying to get the location.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 30; // Meters.
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I call these lines in my viewDidLoad method and I have implemented a didUpdateLocations method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations { 
       self.location = locations.lastObject; 
}
```

For some reason this method is never being called. I have linked the delegate to my interface and have created properties for my `CLLocationManager` and `CLLocation`. I have tried running the code in the simulator and on an iPhone with the same result.

Comment: Does your class conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` - also check out `locationServicesEnabled` - go to Privacy and make sure location services in enabled for your app. Did you accept the app's use of your location services?

Comment: Where do you actually NSLog altitude and longitude? I think you should add more codes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on a device rather than the simulator?

Comment: I have tried it on a iPhone 5s and an iPad, both unable to get the correct location.

Comment: Have you added the CGLocationManagerdelagate to the header? Also check privacy on the device to ensure location is enabled.